# Let $ f(z) $ be a holomorphic function in the unit disk $ \textbf{D} $ and let $ f(0)=0 $. Prove that $ |f(z)+f(-z)|\leq 2|z|^2.$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on solving this problem. I imagine that we will need to use Schwarz lemma, but I don't know how to proceed. Any hints would be appreciated.

Let $ f(z) $ be a holomorphic function in the unit disk $ \mathbb{D} $ and let $ f(0)=0 $. Prove that
$$ |f(z)+f(-z)|\leq 2|z|^2.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you also need to assume $f$ maps the unit disk to itself, otherwise this isn't true (consider $f(z) = \frac{z}{z - 1})$ and the Schwarz lemma doesn't apply.

Consider the function
$$g(z) = \frac{f(z) + f(-z)}{2}.$$
By the Schwarz lemma we have $\vert g(z) \vert \leq \vert z \vert$. Now observe that $g$ is even, so you can apply the Schwarz lemma again to the function $h(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z}$.